# discriminated union boolean tag inference fails for the 'false' case

Tags: typescript, type-inference, discriminated-union

**EDIT**: The problem was simply not using strict mode, which correctly disallowed the types with `null` properties and correctly inferred both true and false cases.

I'm writing a discriminated union where the tag is a boolean, but trying to use `!x.tag` as a type guard doesn't work. I suspected the reason is because a falsey value like `null` or `undefined` would also count, but defining the tag type as `NonNullable<true>` and `NonNullable<false>` didn't help -- I'm still able to create an object of type `isTrue` or `isFalse` with `tag: null`. This would make it fail the type guard even in the truthy case, so I don't understand what I'm missing. Example code:

```js
// definitions:

interface isTrue {
    tag: NonNullable<true>;
    data: string;
}

interface isFalse {
    tag: NonNullable<false>;
    data: number;
}

type either = isTrue | isFalse;


// playing around:

const falsy: isFalse = { tag: null, data: 5 }; // would expect this not to be ok but it is

const truthy: isTrue = { tag: null, data: 'a' }; // this is also allowed

decider({ tag: null, data: 4 }) // a legal call since the argument is valid as a isFalse object.

function decider(x: either) {
    if (x.tag) { // inferred as isTrue
        x.data
        x.tag
    } else { // still a union
        x.data
        x.tag
    }
}
```

I've also tried putting `!x.tag` in the `if` clause and leaving the `true` case to the `else` clause, but in both cases the `true` clause is inferred while the `false` one isn't.

Comment: [Can't reproduce the issue](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAmAZwCpQK4oN4BQyxyYcA5gFzIByA9iDdgDbNwBGzEAPGDhAD4A3ERIATOGWpo+ociIC+BUJFiIU6AGJxmafKOJkqtBk1Ycu3eLsEiSyCVOQhsAW3bRFBMAE8ADigQwGAAFtDIALyomPzIAD7R2jYiKtDwSNEA6nRQYsiE9kbUAOQA7jlixXbiknDSsiDyBEoECAwyyNZoPtRaOnqR+aQU1C6sADQOtdQArMgKIq3tYKQ4oT3RWLiDeMPGY8yTjnXIxXDF84tiEAjA11AAFLtFziyHU04ALPMAlIsw2BACDAwAYDhud2gDwAHtQgqFoD98gZUDBkDCAHRGJEFewkaEY47VPHIAlGYnzZAQGzIknEAlElH2MkUClKBRAA)

Comment: true, I compared flags and the matter stemmed from not being in strict mode.

Comment: So, problem resolved then?

Comment: Definitely, just not sure if etiquette is to leave it up in case anyone comes up with a similar issue or to delete.

Comment: The etiquette is to close as "problem can't be reproduced, or was caused by a typo" 

Comment: I can't find that option anywhere, care to explain?

Comment: Click on the close question link at the bottom of the question, then select `off topic > reason #5`